# Как посмотреть результат возврата метода HTTP TRACE с сервера?

Tags: http

Поставил расширение [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/restclient/?src=userprofile) для Firefox. В нем можно выбирать метод, хост, request header, request body. Что нужно вводить для метода TRACE?

Answer (score 2):

Вот небольшой пример кода, который отправит TRACE-запрос на указанный сервер:

```
<script>
function sendTrace () {
var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xmlHttp.open("TRACE", "any_host",false);
xmlHttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlHttp.responseText;
alert(xmlDoc);
}
</script>

<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON OnClick="sendTrace();" VALUE="Send Trace Request">
```

any_host - адрес хоста, который поддерживает метод TRACE.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но ActiveXObject работает только в IE. То, что можно использовать XMLHTTPRequest, я знаю. Но мне нужны конкретный строки HTTP запроса. Например для GET:

GET /wiki/страница HTTP/1.1
Host: ru.wikipedia.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; ru; rv:1.9b5) Gecko/2008050509 Firefox/3.0b5
Accept: text/html
Connection: close
(пустая строка)

Что-то подобное мне нужно для TRACE. А еще непонятно как преодолеваются доменные ограничения, т.е. наверное можно послать такой запрос к домену только от скрипта, принадлежащему этому же домену.